# Bootstrap 3 - Make a navbar's links grow vertically with the size of a brand image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It's probably simplest if I start with a screenshot of my problem, and then describe what I want to have happen.  So, this is my current navbar:

[image: Current Navbar]

As you can see, the links on the right hand side have their text positioned at the top.  And, this is what the hover effect I created is currently doing:

[image: Hover Effect]

I'd like to do two things:

1. Make the height of the `<li>` elements in the navbar's `<ul>` be the full height of the navbar itself.  In other words, make it so that the hover effect changes the background color of the links for the entire height of the navbar rather than the little boxes it's creating now.
2. Center the link text within them.

I'm not sure where to start, as my CSS skills are weak, and the navbar stuff is placed in several different CSS classes.

My navbar code is currently:

```
<nav id="k9nav-outer" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#k9nav-inner">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/k9logo.png" alt="K9SportsCenter" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="k9nav-inner">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Plans</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My current custom CSS is:

```
#k9nav-outer {
    background-color: #428bca;
}

#k9nav-inner ul li:hover {
    background-color: black;
}

#k9nav-inner ul li:hover a {
    box-shadow: 0 -2px red inset;
}

#k9nav-inner ol li:active {
    background-color: black;
}

#k9nav-outer .navbar-brand,
#k9nav-inner .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

The rest of the CSS is what a standard Bootstrap 3 project comes with when you click 'Download' on their site.

Using Chrome's developer's tools, I see that the `<li>` elements have a height of 50px.  That value must be generated, as I haven't specified any particular height for them.  Should I just do something like:

```
.navbar li {
    height: 100%;
}
```

To make them re-size along with the brand image?

Comment: You could start from adding some relevant code here; Or creating a fiddle to demonstrate the issue in action.

Comment: Does the nav bar have a fixed height?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  No fixed height from what I can tell.  I haven't added one, and using Chrome's developer's tools, it looks like there's a formulated/calculated/default/whatever the proper term is height of 50px for the list items.  I'll add this info as an edit to bump my question up to maybe get more eyes on it.

Comment: Do you know the height of your brand image, or will it change?

Comment: It will be fixed.  I'm actually going to shrink it a bit because right now the mobile version of the navigation gets pushed up awkwardly above the brand image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `line-height` of the navbar links to the height of your image.

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height:100px;
}
```

Example custom navbar with image: http://bootply.com/108341